# Not able to access event defined in a class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to subscribe a event but it is showing error on the mentioned line. Can anyone tell me what the problem in my code is?

I am new to programming, so kindly please provide a detailed answer. Thanks in advance

```
namespace Events
{
    delegate void MyEventHandler();

    internal class ArrayListExamplePublisher : ArrayList
    {
        public event MyEventHandler objMyEventHandler;

        void OnAdded()
        {
            if (objMyEventHandler != null)
            {
                objMyEventHandler();
            }
        }

        public override int Add(object? value)
        {
            OnAdded();
            return base.Add(value);
        }
    }

    public class ArrayListExample
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();

            // Here I get an error
            arrayList.objMyEventHandler += () => Console.WriteLine("Object Added"); 
            
            arrayList.Add(1);
            arrayList.Add("4");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding the event to `ArrayListExamplePublisher`, not `ArrayList`, so when you try to assign that event on an `ArrayList`, it fails.

You can't add an event to a class externally in C# - you'd have to modify the definition of `ArrayList`, which you can't do.

You *could* do:

```
ArrayListExamplePublisher arrayList = new ArrayListExamplePublisher();
```

and set the event on *that*, but it's not clear if that's what you want.

Side note: The framework already has `ObservableCollection<T>` that has events for when the collection is modified (and is strongly-typed, unlike `ArrayList`.

Comment: Hi @MuhammadAsharBhatti You can click the √ beside the answer to mark it as the solution and it will make it easier to be found by others who meet similar issue in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Your lambda expression has to match the delegate type for the event.

Most events take two arguments, so this should probably work:

```
arrayList.objMyEventHandler += ( s, e ) => Console.WriteLine("Object Added");
```

Comment: The delegate type does not have any parameters, so that's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So i have figured it out
As i am inheriting the class ArrayList so I should use object of child class but i was using the object of parent class. This works perfectly

```
ArrayListExamplePublisher objArrayListExamplePublisher = new ArrayListExamplePublisher();
            objArrayListExamplePublisher.Added += () => Console.WriteLine("Object Added");
            objArrayListExamplePublisher.Add(1);
            objArrayListExamplePublisher.Add("4");
```

Comment: In fact, you shouldn't do any of that. You very probably should use an ObservableCollection.

Comment: And you especially shouldn't be using `ArrayList` in any way, for anything, ever, anymore. *For 17 years*, there have been better alternatives.